# Ubuntu 14.04 NVidia proprietry 346 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04, I have a NVidia Quadro K1000M on my Elitebook 8570w. I have added this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

And installed `nvidia-346 nvidia-settings`. Running `nvidia-settings` shows me this:

[image: Screenshot]

However, running `sudo software-proprietry-gtk` show me

[image: Screenshot]

NVidia-346 is *not* listed.

So am I still using the Nouveau drivers? If I pick any of the NVidia proprietry drivers from the list, rebooting will result in "System running in low graphics mode", "Could not detect display, graphics card etc." ([How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)).

How can I use the NVidia proprietry drivers?

Comment: See newer answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: The xorg-edgers *repackage* the binary proprietary NVidia driver as "X.Org X-Server Nouveau".  So that's why you see what you see in the "additional drivers" screen.

Now to see the exact version of the NVidia driver you're using you have to start `nvidia-settings` as you did or go to a terminal and execute `nvidia-settings --version`

This means that the next time the xorg-edgers repackage the newer driver, it'll get updated automatically, contrarily to installing the NVidia binary driver.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Finally. This works for me after 2 days searching.

- ThinkPad W530
- Ubuntu 15.04
- K1000M

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 though :/ (no nvidia-346 nvidia package)